# iOS: Send NSData via Bluetooth and don't let Apple reject it

Tags: ios, bluetooth, nsdata, core-bluetooth

Is there a way to send NSData via Bluetooth without Apple rejecting it because it is made with GameKit API or something? If yes, how? I saw CoreBluetooth, but is it possible to send NSData via CoreBluetooth? If yes, how? I know, many questions, I hope you guys know the answers. ;)

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem about sending data using GameKit? Why would Apple reject it and how?

Comment: Apple will not let me Publish this App in the AppStore, they will reject it from the AppStore! ;)

Comment: they will reject your app because of using Gamekit??? o_0

Comment: I just misundersdood a Post in a Blog, soo sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with CoreBluetooth.

See the latest sample code - [BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927).

Answer (score 0):

I just misundersdood a Post in a Blog! I shurely can use GameKit to do this, I am so sorry for this dumb question!